# Return null instead of org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: Java

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table called `ad_session` which logs user sessions. I am using Java to get a list of all successful sessions from that table. I then loop through that list to get the user for each session (which is a foreign key to the `ad_user` table). I then get the client that belongs to that user, and I add the client to a list. However, one of the users no longer exists, so my code stops running and it gives throws the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [ADUser#76A5C22E6D2446A399AE9AD7C1DED0C7]
```

This is my original code:

```
List<Session> sessions = getAllSuccessfulSessionsInTable();
List<Client> clientsForThatDay = new ArrayList<>();

try {
   for (Session session : sessions) {
     //code fails when trying to get the non-existent user:
     User user = session.getCreatedBy();
     Client userClient = user.getClient();
     clientsForThatDay.add(userClient);
   }
} catch (Exception e) {     
     log.error("Error getting client from user: ", e);
}
```

I assumed that when getting a non-existent record, it would return null, so this is what I tried:

```
List<Session> sessions = getAllSuccessfulSessionsInTable();
List<Client> clientsForThatDay = new ArrayList<>();

//Create new user object to stand in place of the non-existent user
User deletedUser = new User();
deletedUser.setName("Deleted User");

//Create new client object to stand in place of the non-existent client
Client deletedUserClient = new Client();
deletedUserClient.setName("Unknown Client");

try {
  for (Session session : sessions) {
    //check is User is null, if it is, use the deletedUser object, otherwise, use the existing user
    User user = session.getCreatedBy() == null ? deletedUser : session.getCreatedBy();
    
    Client userClient = user.getName().equals("Deleted User") ? deletedUserClient : user.getClient();
    clientsForThatDay.add(userClient);
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
   log.error("Error getting client from user: ", e);
}
```

However, it is not returning null, it's just throwing the exception and then stopping.
**How can I get it to return null here so I can deal with the missing record without my code stopping?**
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: surround the line of code that throws that with a try catch for that type, in the catch block return null

Comment: Surround the code with try-catch is the wrong solution. There something wrong with the mapping, the database is missing a foreign key, or the way you are deleting entities. Without the mapping it's hard to say, but I suspect you are mapping a many-to-one as lazy even if the association can be null.

Comment: @DavideD'Alto Yes - the database is missing a foreign key - but I need a way to handle this situation without my code failing

Comment: That's what foreign keys are for :) In the table User there is a reference to a row that no longer exist. If you don't want to see the error you need to make sure that when the client is deleted, the table with the reference to it is updated as well.

Comment: @DavideD'Alto Hi Davide - I understand - but unfortunately I have no control over whether the table with the reference is updated as well. I am just creating this code to run on many different instances with tables I have not created. So if I am understanding correctly, that this cannot be handled by my code in any way?

Comment: I've answered your question with some options. But if you cannot touch the database, it's probably better if you don't map it as an association.

Comment: I think you should mention in the question that there are no constraints in the database, or people will close it because of a lack of clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your database is missing a foreign key constraint.
This means that the table mapping `User` has a reference to a row in the table for `Client` that no longer exist.

This can only happen if a client has been deleted without updating the user table. The solution would be to add a foreign key constraint between the tables.

Keep in mind that if the data in your tables are not correct, when Hibernate loads the entity `User`, it will also believe there's a client. This means that `User#getClient` won't be null, and every place in the code where you have a check like `user.getClient() == null` is going to fail. A try-catch approach won't help you with this (unless you set the association to null in case of error, I guess).

The solutions I can think of:

1. Add the foreign key constraint (imho, the best solution)
2. Don't map the association, map `client_id` as an attribute and load the client using a second query or find (I would only do this if you cannot update the database)

   ```java
   class User {
       @Column(name = "client_id")
       Long clientId;
   }

   User user = ...
   Client client = session.find(Client.class, user.getClientId());
   ```
3. You can load the client via `session.find(Client.class, user.getClient().getId())` and set the association with the result:

   ```java
   User user = //...
   Client client = session.find(Client.class, user.getClient().getId());
   user.setClient(client);
   ```
4. Don't map the association at all in `User`, and run a native SQL query to load the client:

   ```
   User user = ...
   String sql = "select * from Client c join User u on c.id = u.client_id where u.id = :uid";
   Client client = session.createNativeQuery(sql, Client.class)
       .setParameter("uid", user.getId())
       .getSingleResultOrNull();
   ```

You can pick what works best for you, but keep in mind that mapping an association without the foreign key constraint, will cause all sort of consistency issues.

I've decided to put option 3 only because, sometimes, people have some impossible situations at work, but I wouldn't recommend it.